# Truncating text within every div with a particular name

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to truncate multiple divs with the same class name, at the moment I'm only able to get it to work on the first occurrence of the div

I would like to truncate multiple divs with the same class name, at the moment I'm only able to get it to work on the first occurrence of the div and not for each div respectively.

```js
var truncate = function (elem, limit, after) {
 if (!elem || !limit) return;
 var content = elem.textContent.trim(); 
 content = content.split(' ').slice(0, limit);
 content = content.join(' ') + (after ? after : '');
 elem.textContent = content;
 
};

var elem = document.querySelector('.truncate');
truncate(elem, 20, '...');
```

```html
<div class="truncate">
 Port tender gun spanker lanyard heave to topmast. Heave down draught piracy loaded to the gunwalls mizzenmast topsail Brethren of the Coast. Lanyard snow Jack Ketch swing the lead maroon spike black jack.
</div>
<div class="truncate">
 Port tender gun spanker lanyard heave to topmast. Heave down draught piracy loaded to the gunwalls mizzenmast topsail Brethren of the Coast. Lanyard snow Jack Ketch swing the lead maroon spike black jack.
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `querySelectorAll` and iterate through them:

```js
var truncate = function(elem, limit, after) {
  if (!elem || !limit) return;
  var content = elem.textContent.trim();
  content = content.split(' ').slice(0, limit);
  content = content.join(' ') + (after ? after : '');
  elem.textContent = content;

};

const elems = [...document.querySelectorAll(".truncate")];
elems.forEach(elem => truncate(elem, 20, "..."));
```

```html
<div class="truncate">
  Port tender gun spanker lanyard heave to topmast. Heave down draught piracy loaded to the gunwalls mizzenmast topsail Brethren of the Coast. Lanyard snow Jack Ketch swing the lead maroon spike black jack.
</div>
<div class="truncate">
  Port tender gun spanker lanyard heave to topmast. Heave down draught piracy loaded to the gunwalls mizzenmast topsail Brethren of the Coast. Lanyard snow Jack Ketch swing the lead maroon spike black jack.
</div>
```